# Two authors of one paper have same surname

Tags: bibtex, citing, apa-style

I am new to using bibtex. I write using APA and I have an issue. There is an article written by two brothers. I need this behavior:

1. When using **textcite**: I want both of them to have initials displayed.
2. When using **parencite**: I want neither of them to have initials displayed.
3. When any of the brothers is mentioned **alone** (different works), I want his initials to be included.

Is this possible to do somehow? I only played around with the uniquename=false option, but it did not result in the behaviour I need.

Thank you in advance :)!

Minimal working example:
**Source.bib:**

```
@article{Stylianides2007,
 author = {Stylianides, Andreas J.},
 journal = {Journal for Research in Mathematics Education},
 number = {3},
 pages = {289--321},
 publisher = {National Council of Teachers of Mathematics},
 title = {Proof and Proving in School Mathematics},
 volume = {38},
 year = {2007}
}

@article{Stylianides&Stylianides2008,
author = { Stylianides, Gabriel J.  and  Stylianides, Andreas J.},
title = {Proof in School Mathematics: Insights from Psychological Research into Students' Ability for Deductive Reasoning},
journal = {Mathematical Thinking and Learning},
volume = {10},
number = {2},
year  = {2008},
publisher = {Routledge},
doi = {10.1080/10986060701854425},
}
```

---

**Main body:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[czech, english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\addbibresource{Source.bib}
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace a~}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\&}{%
  \ifdim\fontdimen1\font>0pt
    \textsl{\symbol{`\&}}%
  \else
    \symbol{`\&}%
  \fi
}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{ }
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{ \& }

\begin{document}

\textcite{Stylianides&Stylianides2008} \\
\parencite{Stylianides&Stylianides2008} \\
\textcite{Stylianides2007}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Welcome. // You should do the following: 1) Provide simplified Source.bib (e.g. with just one of such entries), 2) Provide all code that's needed to compile AND shows your problem (i.e. using all 3 ways of citations you mention). Which means in return: is free of all unecessary code lines. Thank you

Comment: Only two with same surname? Check out https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.12492

Comment: Thank you, could you provide more details on what I am supposed to do? I use Overleaf by the way...